# MFC/COM: Preventing clipboard from being cleared once the application is closed

Tags: caching, mfc, com, clipboard

I'm experiencing a problem: **The OLE clipboard gets cleared once I close my 
application that cached global data into it.**

Here's what I'm doing:

```
class CMyOleDataSource sealed:public COleDataSource{
public:
    CMyOleDataSource(){
        // ctor
        // - target may inform if paste succeeded
        DelaySetData( CEditor::cfPasteSucceeded ); // global const value
        // - cache a plain ANSI text
        char text[]="hello world";
        const HANDLE hText=::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_SHARE,::lstrlen(text)+1); // "+1" = null-char
        ::lstrcpy( (LPSTR)::GlobalLock(hText), text );
        ::GlobalUnlock(hText);
        CacheGlobalData( CF_TEXT, hText );
    }
};
...
COleDataSource *ods=new CMyOleDataSource; // instantiation somewhere in the app
```

Two scenarios of use:

(1) The app caches "hello world", I paste it into NotePad, and close the app - the text remains cached in the clipboard.

(2) The app caches "hello world" and I close the app without pasting it anywhere - the text gets discarded from the clipboard.

Therefore a question - what am I doing wrong? Do I need to yet set anything in the `COleDataSource` object?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour of the OLE clipboard functions. The data is cached in a global context when it is requested for the first time.

If OLE clipboard data is never requested it just get cleared from the clipboard.

To prevent this use [OleFlushClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679707(v=vs.85).aspx) upon exit of your application. Read the docs of the function fur further information.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was instantiating things around the OLE clipboard in a wrong way :-)